# Stop my colleague from watching my X session

Tags: ubuntu, x11

My colleague is watching my X session somehow. lightdm runs with --notcp; no vnc is running; he is not connected via ssh.

What other ways are there and how can I stop him or turn this game around on him?

I'm only used to cooperatively share a session via vnc, so I'm new to this. (I'm on ubuntu 17.04; he is using debian) I also don't want to accidentally turn something off, that is needed.

Please help!

Comment: Speak about this to your colleague, or to a manager. This is a social problem.

Comment: Yes, of course it is. But I need hard evidence first. Otherwise this will go nowhere, he has more pull than I have...

Comment: Your evidence is however you know it's happening. But if you absolutely must, watch network traffic leaving your machine. Identify each packet flow, where it's going and why. And don't approach it as a combative exercise; that'll only make you seem paranoid.

Comment: Are you running X over the network, or just locally on your machine?

Comment: What's your soft evidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on a firewall. Every Ubuntu install comes with `ufw`, which can be used to effectively block all inbound connections.

By default, just running `sudo ufw enable` will be enough. UFW's default rules are to allow all outgoing connections, and deny all incoming. If you need to unblock specific ports for whatever reason, the command is as follows:

```
sudo ufw allow <port_number>
```

If you want more verbose firewall rules, look at the `gufw` package or [this handy reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) for more information as to what UFW can offer you.

Now, this won't work if your coworker (somehow) has something like TeamViewer on your computer, as tools like that can bypass the firewall in some cases. Similarly, this won't work if your coworker has access to your physical machine, as they can just disable/alter your firewall rules. Be sure to lock your session whenever you're not at your computer. If you're really paranoid, also encrypt your hard drive to prevent attacks using recovery mode or a drive sled.

---

As mentioned in the comments, this is a social issue as opposed to a technical issue. If you can prove that your coworker is actually spying on you, that can go a long way. You can use Wireshark or any similar network monitor to see what's going on. X11 will usually run on port 6000, but can go up to 6032 in rare cases. Wireshark [can automatically detect](https://wiki.wireshark.org/X11) X11 in some cases, but not all.

If you're paranoid about your coworker seeing Wireshark running, it comes with a command-line utility called [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html). You can use a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to X) to ensure that the process is completely invisible from the X server. Note, though, that if you open up `top` or your coworker has access to an open shell, it may still be possible to spot the process.

Also, UFW will print "block logs" to your `dmesg` console:

```
[  367.801540] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=[REDACTED] SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.22 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=9359 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8009 DPT=41672 WINDOW=294 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

You can use `grep` to search for `DPT=60*` to see if `ufw` has blocked any requests. Note, however, that just because a port is blocked doesn't mean it's necessarily an attack. Your machine may just be being pinged/scanned by your colleague or some network threat management tool on your network.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he has access to your X11 cookie. If you have that cookie you can access the X server and monitor everything. Typically the cookie resides in a file called `.Xauthority` in your home dir. You can see it with `xauth list`.
So check if if there's a chance your colleague can get/read your `.Xauthority` file. If your home is coming from a network share he may have access to the server it resides on and can access your cookie there.

Or maybe you have explicitely or implicitely run `xhost +`. Then everybody can access your X server and monitor everything. See `man xhost`.